# HTC Droid Incredible 2 - Mobile Data in Germany

Tags: htc-droid-incredible-2

I have an old Verizon branded HTC Droid Incredible 2 running with Android 2.2.1. I got it second hand from a friend from the US, but I live in Germany and I want to use it here. Calling works, WiFi does too, but mobile data connection (UMTS, GPRS, EDGE etc.) does not.

My carrier is o2 (Telefonica), in Germany this means that I am using GSM frequencies around 1800 MHz.

Why does mobile data not work on my smartphone? Is it due to the frequencies, which aren't supported by my phone? Or is there a software trick, maybe trying CyanogenMod?

Thanks in advance!

Here are the details of my phone:
http://m.gsmarena.com/htc_droid_incredible_2-3938.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct answer on my own.

I needed to add an APN to get mobile internet working.

Settings -> Network Settings -> Mobile Networks -> GSM-UMTS-Options -> Access Points -> Press Menu Button -> New APN

Add the information from the following link:

http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/wiki/view/APN_Einstellungen_O2

Have phun =)!